# Removing the generated hash when uploading an image with easy_admin / @Vich\Uploadable

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

My problem is simple but complicated at the same time.

Basically when you upload a image with easy_admin. The image get's a hash.

Like so:

```
/uploads/images/5f17449f4932f_image004.jpg
```

Is there any way to remove the generated hash before the image name ?

Here is my Entity:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

 /**
 * Image
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @var string
 */
private $image = '';

/**
 * ImageFile
 *
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="images", fileNameProperty="image")
 * @var File
 */
private $imageFile;
```

Is there a setting that I may use in the easy_admin.yml config ?

```
 form:
    fields:
      - { property: 'imageFile', label: 'Image', type: 'vich_image'}
```

Let me know if any other information is needed.
Thank you.

UPDATE: The class

```
namespace App\Service\FileNamer;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\PropertyMapping;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\NamerInterface;

class FileNamer implements NamerInterface
{
   public function name($object, PropertyMapping $mapping): string
   {
       /* @var $file UploadedFile */
       $file = $mapping->getFile($object);

       return  $file->getClientOriginalName();
   }
}
```

Easy_admin

```
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        images:
            uri_prefix:         '%upload_images_folder%'
            upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../public%upload_images_folder%'
            namer:
                service: App\Service\FileNamer
        videos:
            uri_prefix:         '%upload_videos_folder%'
            upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../public%upload_videos_folder%'
            namer:
                service: vich_uploader.namer_origname
        pdfs:
            uri_prefix:         '%upload_pdfs_folder%'
            upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../public%upload_pdfs_folder%'
            namer:
                service: vich_uploader.namer_origname
```

Comment: The reason hash is added to file names is to prevent conflicts when files with same name are uploaded, I guess you understand this. So the question is: what do you want to achieve? E.g. what is the reason you want hash removed?

Comment: Well it would just make my life more easier. Do you have any tipps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own custom namer class. Just implement `Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\NamerInterface` and add it to `vich_uploader` configuration.
https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/file_namer/howto/create_a_custom_file_namer.md

Comment: Hey when i try your method i get the following when i try to debug:container  ```Service "App\Service\FileNamer.images": Parent definition "App\Service\FileNamer" does not exist.``` . Here is how i added it     ```namer:  service: App\Service\FileNamer```

Comment: Did you create class `App\Naming\MyNamer`?

Comment: It's called ```namespace App\Service\FileNamer;```

Comment: Yes, sorry. So you created `App\Service\FileNamer` that is implementing `Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\NamerInterface`, right?

Comment: Hey i added it to the post. So you can see it. Should clear things up :D

Comment: You need to register `FileNamer` as a service and refer to it by service name. Check this for reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441537/vichuploaderbundle-namer-parent-definition-does-not-exist